# Combined spring-damper in circuitikz for representing viscoelasticity

Tags: circuitikz

I am hoping someone can help me draw a combined spring-damper in `circuitikz`, similar to the existing `spring` and `damper` components, for use in representing a viscoelastic element.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0)
    to[spring,*-] (1,0)
    to[damper,-*] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: circuitikz spring and damper]

I imagine it looking something like the attached drawing.

[image: combined spring-damper]

Comment: This will need another component... I can try a shot at it. I opened an issue on the circuitikz github... https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/183

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added the new component (which, I admit, could be handsomer --- patches welcome) to the pre-release of `circuitikz`; you can get it and see the manual online here: https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/

The component is something like this:

[image: The correct image]

and, more important, I added a sort-of howto on how to define new components.